# How can smt2 file be optimised?

Tags: z3, smt, z3py

Is any way how I can read smt2 file and optimize it somehow? Decrease number of lines, remove unnecessary conditions etc.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is rather vague, and it's not clear exactly what this "optimization" would do. Reducing the size of a file hardly serves any purpose, so I presume you actually mean getting a "simple" but "equi-satisfiable" smt2 description. That is, the "optimized" file would have the exact same `sat`/`unsat` status, with the exact same models as the original; but somehow "simpler."

If that's the case, you really need to be very clear about what "simpler" means. Simpler as in "easier to solve"? Simpler as in "easier to read for humans"?

Assuming you mean "easier to solve" (which is the interesting case I believe), then what you're asking for is how to determine if two sets of constraints are equi-satisfiable; which in general is an NP-complete problem. So, no; there won't be an easy way to do this. Can you drop "redundant" assertions: Sure, but that'd mean you need to find what those are, and that'll be a costly analysis of the benchmark itself.

So, without knowing any further detail and specifying what "optimize" means, the answer is a simple "no, there's no easy way." But each case is different, and different domains (for instance integer-difference logic) might make it easier to spot unnecessary constraints. You'll really have to be very specific about what you mean by optimizing to get a better answer.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. Yes, I would like to get the "optimized" file with exact same sat/unsat status/model, but somehow “simple”. And I’m interested in any out of box solution. For example,
1. Remove all unused var/fun which is not used in rules or
2. Equivalent sets of rules (like in Math, simpler sets of equations).

Comment: Cool. As I mentioned, removing variables won't give you much since the SMT-solver can easily drop them anyway. And "simplifying" equations in this way is really what an SMT-solver does to see if it can reduce it to `false` to detect `unsat` essentially, so there's no "out-of-the-box" way to do this in any easy way. You can do some local rewrites, but I doubt they'll help at all as the solver itself does them too. It helps to be very clear about your goal. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have SMT files with CHCs (Constrained Horn Clause) that are produced after the symbolic execution of some programs. I would like to reduce the number of uninterpreted predicates, merging rules etc.

Comment: SMT solvers apply a lot of simplifications, tactics, and pre/in-processing all by themselves. If you depend on a specific rewrite rule that's necessary to solve your particular problems efficiently, you can look into writing e.g. a Z3 tactic for it. The only out-of-the-box solution is the SMT solver itself.